# Setting Android environment variable

Tags: android, ionic-framework

I've got to set ANDROID_HOME and modify path in Windows to run ionic app.Could someone say some way to do it?I 've read some topic here about this argomenti but i can't solve this problem.I've installed android studio in its default folder so I've already got Android tools.

Answer (score 1):

This is how your Environment variables looks like.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Click on Start menu. Then right click on Computer and select Properties option
2. This would open the System Properties window as shown below. Now from the Advanced Tab, click on Environment Variables button
3. From the Environment Variables window,You can modify paths.